# extract a key-pair value from list of json SQL (json_extract_path_text)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, analytics

I have a column like this

[{"itemCode":"ABC","amount":20.4},{"itemCode":"XYZ","amount":575}]

I need to use json_extract_path_text to extract 'itemcode's amount for every row in column.

Any help?

Comment: the result should be column 'Extract' with value 575

Answer (score 0):

You can use json_parse instead of json_extract_path_text.

For example, you have a table with column items of varchar type.

Cast column to super data type with json_parse, next unnest result
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html#unnest

```sql
with temp as (select json_parse(items) as items from test.temp)
select item."itemCode"::text, item.amount
from temp as t, t.items as item;
```